# Fixing AngularJS 1.2.0 [$parse:isecprv] errors

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angularjs, couchdb

AngularJS 1.2.0 just got released, and there's an instant problem for `CounchDB` and `MongoDB` users:

When trying to access some JSON data preceded by an underscore, like `{{data._id}}` Angular 1.2.0 gives the following error:

```
 Error: [$parse:isecprv]
```

There is discussion about this [here on the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24parse%3aisecprv).

Is there a way to disable this 'feature', or overcome it?

Comment: @elclanrs True, although at least in my case I use `MongoDB`'s `._id` field all throughout my app and this would mean a whole lot of messing around with data fields. Yours may be the only option but I'm hoping there are some possible ways to disable the feature completely rather than changing my database design.

Comment: This is, in my opinion a bad move by the angular.js maintainers. Start reading here for workarounds and more information: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4509

Answer (score 4):

To disable this 'feature' in 1.2.0, comment out lines 9097 till 9101. These 5 lines are responsible for `Error: [$parse:isecprv]`:

```
if (name.charAt(0) === '_' || name.charAt(name.length-1) === '_') {
throw $parseMinErr('isecprv',
    'Referencing private fields in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: {0}',
    fullExpression);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like we'll need to wait until 1.2.1 has been released.

**Nov 13 2013** [Vojta](https://github.com/vojtajina) said [the following](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4509#issuecomment-28465210) about this 'feature':

> Guys, sorry for the troubles this change caused. This "feature" was
>   mostly for people using Closure compiler and Google JS style, but I
>   didn't realize that many people were relying on accessing _*
>   properties in templates. For now we are reverting that change
>   ([4ab16aa](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/4ab16aaaf762e9038803da1f967ac8cb6650727d)).
>
> ***We gonna release 1.2.1 (which will contain this "fix") within next
>   days.***
>
> The main outcome of this issue is: we should not put any breaking
>   changes into RC. Lesson learned.

**Update - Nov 15, 2013:** [AngularJS 1.2.1 underscore-empathy reverts hiding "private" properties](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/11/angularjs-121-underscore-empathy.html).

> We introduced "private" properties (for properties prefaced with an
>   underscore) in 1.2 thinking that this would be a fairly
>   uncontroversial change. Oops! Apologies (and thank you) to the folks
>   who filed bugs alerting us to the larger consequences in your code of
>   making this breaking change. We've reverted this feature.